# How to make key value pair array when chekbox checked using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have multiple checkbox, when i check a checkbox two key value pair will generate.
Like this : `Object {id: "101", name: "example"}`
This will generate for every checkbox checked and i want for multiple checkbox checked array. look like this :

```
[{id:"id1",name:"name1"},{id:"id2",name:"name2"}]
```

What I have done

```
$('.chkCompare').click(function(event) {
    var value = [],
        projectName = {},
        span = $(this).attr('id'),
        value = $('.chkCompare:checked').map(function() {
            $('#span' + span).text('ADDED').css({
                "color": "green"
            });
            projectName['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
            projectName['name'] = $(this).attr('title');
            return value.push(projectName);
        }).get();
});
```

When I uncheck checkbox they will be remove from array and want to prevent check maximum 3 checkbox `if >3` then show an alert box.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle.net link with your current code?

Comment: Don't try to "remove from the array" - just rebuild the array each time from the list of `:checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
      var arr = {};
       var count = 0;
      $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){            
         if(count++<3){
           arr[this.id] =this.name;
         }else{
           $(this).prop('checked', false);
         }

      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `length` property of `:checked` checkbox's. Based on your  condition and use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to cancel the default action.

```js
$('.chkCompare').click(function(event) {
  var checkedElemets = $('.chkCompare:checked');
  if (checkedElemets.length > 3) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Only 3 checkbox can be checked');
  }

  var values = checkedElemets.map(function() {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.title
    };
  }).get();

  console.log(values)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCompare" title='t1' id='i1' />
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCompare" title='t2' id='i2'/>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCompare" title='t3' id='i3'/>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCompare" title='t4' id='i4'/>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCompare" title='t5' id='i5'/>
```